# Trying to add a list of posts to my homepage instead of a separate page in Gatsby using Contentful

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I wish to place a list of posts on my home page instead of having to create a seperate dynamic page. This is my `gatsby-node.js` file

```
// DYNAMICALLY CREATE PAGES FOR EACH POST
module.exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;
  const postTemplate = path.resolve('src/templates/news.js');
  const postResult = await graphql(`
    query {
      allContentfulPost {
        edges {
          node {
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  // Handle errors
  if (postResult.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild('Error while running GraphQL query.');
    return;
  }

  // Create the pages for each markdown file
  postResult.data.allContentfulPost.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      component: postTemplate,
      path: `/news/${node.slug}`,
      context: {
        slug: node.slug,
      },
    });
  });

  // PAGINATION FOR BLOG POSTS
  const postsResult = await graphql(`
    {
      allContentfulPost(sort: { fields: date, order: DESC }, limit: 1000) {
        edges {
          node {
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  if (postsResult.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild('Error while running GraphQL query.');
    return;
  }

  // Create blog-list pages
  const posts = postsResult.data.allContentfulPost.edges;
  const postsPerPage = 12;
  const postNumPages = Math.ceil(posts.length / postsPerPage);
  Array.from({ length: postNumPages }).forEach((_, i) => {
    createPage({
      path: i === 0 ? '/' : `/news/${i + 1}`,
      component: path.resolve('./src/templates/news-list.js'),
      context: {
        limit: postsPerPage,
        skip: i * postsPerPage,
        postNumPages,
        currentPage: i + 1,
      },
    });
  });
};
```

And this is my `news-list.js` file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, graphql } from 'gatsby';

import Layout from '../components/layout';
import SEO from '../components/seo';

export const query = graphql`
  query ($skip: Int!, $limit: Int!) {
    allContentfulPost(sort: { fields: date, order: DESC }, limit: $limit, skip: $skip) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          slug
          date(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const NewList = (props) => {
  // const { postNumPages } = props.pageContext;

  const posts = props.data.allContentfulPost.edges;

  return (
    <Layout>
      <SEO title='News' />

      {posts.map(({ node }) => {
        const title = node.title || node.slug;
        return (
          <div className='container mx-auto prose prose-lg'>
            <div className='mb-2'>
              <Link to={`/posts/${node.slug}`}>
                <h3 className='underline font-sans mb-1'>{title}</h3>
              </Link>

              <div className='flex items-center justify-between'>
                <span className='font-mono text-sm'>{node.date}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default NewList;
```

I have tried to import the above `news-list.js` as component from my templates folder into my `index.js` folder. However I am getting the Error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'allContentfulPost' of undefined`

But if i add `path: i === 0 ? '/news' :` /news/${i + 1}`,` into my node file and go to localhost/news i get the list of posts.

But I want them on the home page.. So i thought If I was to just have `/` it would work turns out no.

How can i get the posts that are listed at `LH/news` to be displayed on my homepage instead.

#### Update

New Component after latest answer

```
import React from 'react';
import { useStaticQuery, graphql, Link } from 'gatsby';

import Layout from '../components/layout';

// import News from '../components/news';
// import NewsList from '../templates/news-list';

export const query = graphql`
  {
    allContentfulPost(sort: { fields: date, order: DESC }, limit: 1000) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          slug
          date(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const Index = ({ data }) => {
  const { site } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            companyname
          }
        }
      }
    `
  );

  return (
    <Layout>
      <section className='c-mt-10'>
        <div className=''>
          <div className='font-mono md:flex md:justify-between'>
            <div className='mb-5'>
              <a href={`mailto:hello@${site.siteMetadata.companyname}.co.uk`}>
                hello@pfb{site.siteMetadata.companyname}.co.uk
              </a>
              <br />
              <br />
              <tel>+44 020 3925 6054</tel>
            </div>

            <a
              href='https://www.google.com/maps/place/Warnford+Court,+29+Throgmorton+St,+London+EC2N+2AT/@51.5154096,-0.0890419,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x48761cacb440b98d:0x9742679143333ff!8m2!3d51.5154096!4d-0.0868479'
              target='_blank'
              rel='noreferrer'>
              <address className='text-right'>
                Warnford Court
                <br />
                29 Throgmorton Street
                <br /> London, EC2N 2AT
              </address>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div>
          <h2>Company News</h2>
          <ul>
            {data.allContentfulPost.edges.map(({ node }) => (
              <li key={node.title}>
                <Link to={node.slug}>{node.title}</Link>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>
    </Layout>
  );
};
export default Index;
```

Comment: Is news-list.js a Gatsby page component (i.e. does it live in the pages folder)?

Comment: no this lives in the templates dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing a lot of concepts.

One thing is the `gatsby-node.js` queries, useful to create dynamic pages based on dynamic data (from Contentful CMS in your case) based on a parameter (`slug` in your case).

Another thing is [page queries](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/), a way of retrieving data in a top-level components (pages or templates, not components).

If you want to list all your post in your homepage, you just need to create a GraphQL query and loop through the results just like:

```
const IndexPage = ({ data }) => {

   return <Layout> 
    <ul>
    {data.allContentfulPost.edges.map(({node})=> <li key={node.title}><Link to={node.slug}>{title}</Link></li>)}
    </ul>
   </Layout>

}

export const query = graphql`
    {
      allContentfulPost(sort: { fields: date, order: DESC }, limit: 1000) {
        edges {
          node {
            title
            slug
            date(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
          }
        }
      }
    }
`;
```

When using page queries, your data is stored inside `props.data` so you can destructure them directly into `data`.

In your case, you were importing a template inside a page, which doesn't make much sense because you don't have, among other things, the query.

Comment: That make sense I have added a new component with your updates but still getting the same error :(

Comment: As I said, page queries are only available in top-level components (pages). It can't be an isolated component, it must be on the homepage itself. If you copy-paste the snippet, should work alone.

Comment: perfect this works...i can now just rebuild the index page around it

Comment: @mrpbennett you can useStaticQuery in regular old components, check out the docs: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/use-static-query/

Comment: Yes of course but to me, it's not the purpose of static query in this case (conceptually). They behave slightly different than page queries and rehydrates (they're being triggered in each render) the component differently. But you're right, it's another way of fetching data